# 2 excerpts in theme functions in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the code below

```
add_action('the_excerpt','limit_the_content'); 
function limit_the_content($content){
  $settings = get_option('mytheme_options'); 
  $word_limit = $settings['numberofwordsexcerpt']; 
  $words = explode(' ', $content); 
  return implode(' ', array_slice($words, 0, $word_limit)); 
}

add_action('the_excerpt_slider','limit_the_content_slider'); 
function limit_the_content_slider($content_slider){
  $settings = get_option('mytheme_options'); 
  $word_limit_slider = $settings['numberofwordsexcerptslider']; 
  $words_slider = explode(' ', $content_slider); 
  return implode(' ', array_slice($words_slider, 0, $word_limit_slider)); 
}
```

And i am trying to trigger the second function in index.php with

```
<?php the_excerpt_slider(); ?>
```

and I get the error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function the_excerpt_slider() in
```

The first one that i am triggering it works well with

```
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
```

Please help me.

Comment: Where is your the_excerpt_slider() function ?

Comment: @Laxmana I thought that it is ok if it;s declared like this `add_action('the_excerpt_slider','limit_the_content_slider'); 
function limit_the_content_slider($content_slider){`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At add_action documentation it says that

```
add_action( $hook, $function_to_add, $priority, $accepted_args );
```

> $hook : The name of the action to which $function_to_add is hooked. (See Plugin API/Action Reference for a list of action hooks). Can also be the name of an action inside a theme or plugin file, or the special tag "all", in which case the function will be called for all hooks)

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action

So or you either declare a action hook that is provided from wordpress core (See the list here : http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) or you can provide your action but this action, in your case the_excerpt_slider();, has to be declare somewhere in your function.php file. So that's whay you get this error. the_excerpt(); is working fine because is a core function of wordpress.

**UPDATE**

```
add_action('the_excerpt','limit_the_content'); 
function limit_the_content($content){
  global $post;
  if('slider' == get_post_type($post->ID)){
    $settings = get_option('mytheme_options'); 
    $word_limit_slider = $settings['numberofwordsexcerptslider']; 
    $words_slider = explode(' ', $content_slider); 
    return implode(' ', array_slice($words_slider, 0, $word_limit_slider)); 
  }else{
    $settings = get_option('mytheme_options'); 
    $word_limit = $settings['numberofwordsexcerpt']; 
    $words = explode(' ', $content); 
    return implode(' ', array_slice($words, 0, $word_limit));
  }
}
```

In this line of code :

```
'slider' == get_post_type($post->ID)
```

the 'slider' is the name of your custom post. You have to change it to your defined name. You can find it if you go to the admin panel and go where all your sliders are shown up. In the url you should see something like :

```
http://yoururl/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=slider
```

so the name of your custom post is after the `?post_type=`

Also inside your file you should change the `<?php the_excerpt_slider(); ?>` to `<?php the_excerpt(); ?>`

Comment: I am trying to understand, it's not your fault :) I am a noob.

Comment: :). Your question help me also to understand custom hooks!

Comment: :) hmm still torturing.

Comment: Slider is smth like this `<div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
 <?php query_posts( 'category_name=Uncategorized&posts_per_page=3' ); 
  while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
          <?php the_post_thumbnail(array(980,400)); ?>
          <div id="htmlcaption" class="nivo-html-caption">
     <?php the_excerpt_slider(); ?>
          </div>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
 <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
        </div>
        <!-- End Slider -->`

Comment: Ah now i understand what you mean but Custom Post, nope it's not a custom post. I have it in the options of the theme and it's echo'ed like above. It's by category and number of posts, and it;s available only in the index.php

Comment: Xmm you have to find a way to check if your post is set to be shown for the slider or not.

Comment: The fact is that there is no custom post, it's only a slider in the index.php that gets option from Theme options. I need to know how can i register a custom function somehow. Like to register 'the_excerpt_slider', tried with `add_filter` but doesn't work.

Comment: Got it, i added myself also an answer, though thank you for your answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to make it work, here is it how. I needed to declare instead of `the_excerpt`, i declared on the one for the slider `the_content` and added action after each function, it was before.

```
function limit_the_content_slider($content_slider){
  $settings = get_option('mytheme_options'); 
  $word_limit_slider = $settings['numberofwordsexcerptslider']; 
  $words_slider = explode(' ', $content_slider); 
  return implode(' ', array_slice($words_slider, 0, $word_limit_slider)); 
}
add_action('the_excerpt','limit_the_content_slider');

function limit_the_content($content){
  $settings = get_option('mytheme_options'); 
  $word_limit = $settings['numberofwordsexcerpt']; 
  $words = explode(' ', $content); 
  return implode(' ', array_slice($words, 0, $word_limit)); 
}
add_action('the_content','limit_the_content');
```